# Is that possible to run "spark-submit" in databricks without creating jobs ? if yes ! What is the possiblities,

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-submit

I am trying to execute spark-submit in databricks workspace notebook without creating jobs, Help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible like one would do with /bin/spark-submit as it does not fit in with their notebook approach to making things easier for less techy persons.

The closest you can get is as stated here: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/examples.html#create-a-spark-submit-job

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Is there any other way to run like that ? Because I am using community edition, I have no chance to create jobs

Comment: no. i did the course recently, community edition not supporting that. get a mapr vm or build own server

Comment: No is also an answer

Answer (score 1):

I just happened across this Stack Overflow question. It *is* possible to *run* a Databricks notebook in a workspace without creating a job for it:

```
/api/2.1/jobs/runs/submit
```

> "Submit a one-time run. This endpoint allows you to submit a workload
> directly without creating a job. Runs submitted using this endpoint
> don’t display in the UI. Use the jobs/runs/get API to check the run
> state after the job is submitted."

Note this part: "...without creating a job..."

https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/submit