# Execute spark-submit in azure databricks without creating new cluster

Tags: azure, pyspark, hql, azure-databricks

So, here is my problem. I have a pyspark job stored in dbfs as I don't have access to databricks repo due to org policy and I cannot create a new cluster when creating a spark-submit job again due to org policy. Is their any way I can execute the pyspark job and pass parameters to it?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172899/is-that-possible-to-run-spark-submit-in-databricks-without-creating-jobs-if) once.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Spark Submit task needs a new cluster. Depending on how your PySpark job is created, you can try following (see in the task type dropdown):

[image]

- Use `Python script` task - it allows to get Python file from DBFS:

[image]

- Use `Python wheel` task - if your code is packaged as wheel file

Both of these tasks are supporting execution on the existing interactive cluster, but it will cost you more.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply. The cluster that spark submit will create is temporary cluster? Does it cost less than this cluster?

Comment: Yes, when you create a temporary cluster for job, than it's usually almost 2 times cheaper than interactive cluster (depends on the tier - standard vs. premium).

Comment: Thanks, so I tried reading the file from dbfs but when I read it into my pyspark code in notebook I get an error message as no such file or directory and then something like /local_disk0/spark-/userfiles-../dbfs:/<my folder>/<myfilename>.
Why is it not finding the file?

Comment: IT depends on how you do it…

Comment: Actually script I'm debugging is add file to hdfs cloudera nameservice path and I'm passing dbfs file path to the function, which is where its giving error.

Comment: sc.addFile should work